# Send data from form after Jquery Validation form

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have already created a jQuery Validation script and already created send data from form to the Firebase database function separately. The function is working good but I am trying to do submit a check function before sending data to the firebase database but it's not working could you please help me guys to create a checking function.

````
    const lastName = document.getElementById('lastName');
    const phone = document.getElementById('phone');
    const login = document.getElementById('login');
    const password = document.getElementById('password');
    const email = document.getElementById('email');
    const addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');

    const database = firebase.database();
    const rootRef = database.ref('admins');

    const fnLen = firstName.value.length;
    const lnLen = lastName.value.length;
    const phLen = phone.value.length;
    const logLen = login.value.length;
    const passLen = password.value.length;
    const emLen = email.value.length;

    // FORMS VALIDATION
  function validateForms(form){
    $(form).validate({
      rules: {
        name: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 2
        },
        phone: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 19,
          maxlength: 19
        },
        password: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 6
        },
        repassword: {
          required: true,
          equalTo: "#password"
        },

        checkbox: "required",
        email:{
          required: true,
          email: true
        }
      },
      messages: {
        name: {
          required: "Укажите свое имя",
          minlength: "Слишком короткое имя"
        },
        phone: {
          required: "Укажите свой номер телефона",
          minlength: "Телефон должен состоять из 12 цифр",
          maxlength: "Телефон должен состоять из 12 цифр"
        },
        password: {
          required: "Введите пароль",
          minlength:"Пароль должен быть не менее 6 символов"
        },
        repassword: {
          required: "Повторите введенный пароль",
          equalTo: "Пароли не совпадают"
        },
        email: {
          required: "Укажите свою электронную почту",
          email: "Неправильно введен адрес почты"
        }
      }
    });
    }
    //validateForms('#registration form');


    $.mask.definitions['9'] = '';
    $.mask.definitions.d = '[0-9]';
    $('input[name=phone]').mask("+992 (dd) ddd-dd-dd");

    addBtn.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
        if(fnLen==0 || lnLen==0 || phLen==0 || logLen==0 || passLen==0 || emLen==0){
            console.log("0");
            validateForms('#registration form');
        }else {
            console.log("1");
            e.preventDefault();
        const autoId =rootRef.push().key
        rootRef.child(autoId).set({
            first_name: firstName.value,
            last_name: lastName.value,
            phone: phone.value,
            login: login.value,
            password: password.value,
            email: email.value
        })
        } 
    }); ```
````

Comment: You are setting the values of the fields on page load from what I see. You should be setting your length variables within your listener function so that they reflect the current state of the fields. In JS primitive types are passed by copy and not by reference, therefor the variables you set on script load will remain the same if not updated.

Comment: Ooo yes thanks i did as you said and its works. Thank you so much for your help!!